# Get today's date minus one Year in Unix (AIX)

Tags: shell, aix

I need to find today's date and then subtract a year and format that date into the YYYY-MM-dd format.

I am able to accomplish this with a script I wrote, but apparently it is only compatible with bash. I need it to be compatible with AIX.

```
lastYear=`date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d 'last year'`
searchDate="$lastYear 00.00.00";
echo "Retrieving data start from $searchDate"
myquery="myquery >= '$searchDate'"
```

The result when run on an AIX machine is that it only passes the "00:00:00" part of the $searchDate, the date does not prefix before the time as I hoped.  What is the safest way to write this for the most compatibility across Linux/Unix variations?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's not bash but GNU!date that subtracts a year. You could install GNU!dateutils on your AIX, or in this case you could do the subtraction in the SQL: now() - interval 1 year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make it so complicated?

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -i year=$( date +%Y )
(( year -= 1 ))
typeset rest=$( date +%m-%d )
echo "${year}-${rest}"
```

This should work in any shell.  If you use sh replace the

```
$( ... )
```

with back tics

```
` ... `
```

But for bash and ksh I use $( ... ) -- just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

***Checkout Updated Section Below***

***Original Answer***

Try this. It uses the `-v` flag to display the result of adjusting the current date by negative one year `-1y`

```
searchDate=$(date -v-1y +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo "Retrieving data start from $searchDate"
myquery="myquery >= '$searchDate'"
```

Here is the output:

`Retrieving data start from 2017-06-21`

Note: I did try to run the lines you provided above in a script file with a bash shebang, but ran into an `illegal time format` error and the output was `00:00:00`. The script I provided above runs cleanly on my unix system.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

---

***Updated Section***

***Visit [`ShellCheck.net`](https://www.shellcheck.net)***

It's a nice resource for testing code compatibility between sh, bash, dash, and ksh(AIX's default) shells.

***Identifying the Actual Issue***

When I entered your code, it clearly identified syntax that is considered legacy and suggested how to fix it, and gave this [link with an example and a great explanation](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006). Here's the output:

```
lastYear=`date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d 'last year'`
          ^__Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
```

So, it looks like you might be able to use the code you wrote, by making one small change:

`lastYear=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d 'last year')`

---

Note: This question already has an accepted answer, but I wanted to share this resource, because it may help others trouble-shoot shell compatibility issues like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for running it on your machine - the illegal timeout must be what was causing the issue. I need to find an online simulator so I can test a shell without bash. The bash I have doesn't seem to like the -v option, but I bet it will work with other unix systems. Thanks for your help, new territory for me!

Comment: @LeeAmes I found this 'shell-checker' (https://www.shellcheck.net) today, and thought of you.  It's kind of amazing. When I entered your code, it clearly identified syntax that is considered legacy and suggested how to fix it, and gave a link with more examples and a great explanation. The ShellChecker supports the following shell types sh/bash/dash/ksh....and from what I read it seems like AIX default shell is the Korn Shell (ksh). Long story short, you might want to bookmark this tool. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that is very kind of you!  My research has showed the same, that AIX is Korn shell based. and I have been searching for a decent emulator. Thank you.